# How to add a function in android app to create a new class like Piazza or Tophat without manually creating new activity and manifest?

Tags: android

I am currently building an app similar Tophat and Piazza at school, but I have no idea how to implement a functionality to allow users to create their own classes. Since every time we need to create a class, we need to manually create a new activity and use startActivity(new intent(this, newActivity)). However, it is not applicable for the functionality I want. Is there a way that we can realize this function?

Comment: The class here means the school classes

Comment: Classes should be a model and you have only one Activity to show any kind of Classes

Answer (score 0):

try to search more you do not need to create new layout or activity for every "school class" layout just preview your data and data came from your db if its remotely or local and it should be local 
so you need to create a web service or use cloud service like firebase.
you just will be adding class or join to class and class data will be saved to your db 
in every time you create "class" you just create a new object of class that represent "school class" to your view

sorry about my weak English^^